# Docker MySQL - cant connect SpringBoot app to MySQL database in docker container using docker-compose

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

Trying to connect Springboot app dicom_viewer: Imagename: **sample** with Mysql: Imagename: **pb_mysql** running in docker container. Error: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure.

**Application.properties file:**

```
#MySQL database connection strings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://pb_mysql:3306/test?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=pb
spring.datasource.password=pb@123

#JPA property settings
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
```

**Docker-compose file:**

```
version: '2'
services:
  pb_mysql:
    container_name: pb_mysql
    restart: always
    image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root123' # TODO: Change this
    volumes:
      - sql-datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
  patient_browser:
    container_name: patient_browser
    restart: always
    image: patient_browser
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./dicom_images:/usr/src/app/dicom_images
  springboot-image:
    container_name: dicom_viewer
    restart: always
    image: sample
    ports: 
      - 8081:8080
volumes:
  sql-datavolume:
networks:
  f4:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./target/springboot-image-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","springboot-image-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

[Database: test, table: pm_of_india](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8v1x.png)

[Docker images, docker ps -a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abbuP.png)

[docker-compose up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTWKw.png)

[Error: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xapq6.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to notice,

## `depends_on`

You kept `pb_mysql` ahead of others in the yaml configuration file. This does not ensure the mysql-server to be up and running ahead of others.

You want to use `depends_on`, so the depended `pb_mysql` will be initiated first.

## `ports`

You are using bridged network, so you need to map 3306 to 3306 for mysql-server.

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  patient_browser:
    container_name: patient_browser
    restart: always
    image: patient_browser
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./dicom_images:/usr/src/app/dicom_images
      - 8081:8080
    depends_on:
      - pb_mysql
  springboot-image:
    container_name: dicom_viewer
    restart: always
    image: sample
    ports: 
      - 8081:8080
    depends_on: # Let mysql-server start first
      - pb_mysql
  pb_mysql:
    container_name: pb_mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306" # Port mapping.
    restart: always
    image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root123' # TODO: Change this
    volumes:
      - sql-datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  sql-datavolume:
networks:
  f4:
    driver: bridge
```

I would avoid using `restart: always` unless I absolutely need it.

The rest looks good to me. Let me know if it is resolved.

Comment: Ya its resolved. I added ur recommendations. But I also declared the config of application.prop in docker-compose. And built the jar again. And it worked

Comment: @Ayush Narayan Is it resolved because you have declared `profile.active=` in docker-compose? Or something else?

Comment: No I didnt declare that. My new docker-compose has : springboot-image:
    container_name: dicom_viewer
    image: sample
    ports: 
      - 8081:8080
    depends_on: # Let mysql-server start first
      - pb_mysql
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://pb_mysql:3306/test
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: pb
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: pb@123
  pb_mysql:
    container_name: pb_mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    restart: always
    image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root123'

Comment: Could you let me know exactly which modification corrected the `docker-compose`? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You are not referencing your network.
Try adding it to your services i.e.:

```
services:
  pb_mysql:
     networks:
          - f4

...
```

Comment: All of the services will use a Compose-provided `default` network, and then since they're all on the same network they will be able to communicate.  It'd be easier to delete the `networks:` block from the bottom of the file.  More details on the `default` network are in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.